# CSS for Line Arrow

Tags: css

Does anyone have any pointers on how I can achieve the following 2 effects (red color) using pure CSS?

I am not asking for entire code but if anybody can guide me in proper direction, that would really be great.

[image]

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Going by the second image, you could use a `:before` and `:after` with rounded corners and a slight angle offset to achieve it. Otherwise I'd just use an SVG

Comment: The best place to look for ideas is CSS Tricks. Otherwise, you could look for ideas on implementing Speech Balloons using CSS.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For second effect you should create for image's container two pseudo-elements :before and :after with border-radius set to desired value. Element :before you should position to left bottom side of container and the element :after you should position to right bottom side. You should also specify widths for each pseudo-element (for example: 50% and 50%, 60% and 40% etc.).

Code for the second effect:

```css
.image {
  position: relative;
  width: 350px;
}

img {
  display: block;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

.image:before {
  content: '';
  display: inline-block;
  background: rgba(255, 0, 0, .5);
  width: 30%;
  height: 120px;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  border-top-right-radius: 15px;
}

.image:after {
  content: '';
  display: inline-block;
  background: rgba(255, 0, 0, .5);
  width: 70%;
  height: 120px;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  right: 0;
  border-top-left-radius: 15px;
}
```

```html
<div class="image">
  <img src="http://placehold.it/350x350">
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks, border radius was something that I was missing. Accepted as correct the answer.

Comment: Code only answers are poor quality and not as useful as an answer with an explanation. Even this answer is correct and accepted, you can improve it writing some explanation on what the code do. You can achieve more upvotes with that.

Answer (score 1):

OK, here is a suggestion for the proper direction.

2. The lower red panel looks to me like two adjoining rectangles. You need to set the widths appropriately, and then for each rectangle round off *one* corner using `border-radius: a b c d`.
3. The effect looks to me like *two* of effect number 2. The red one, and then the same in white, possibly with a `z-index` to make sure that it (partly) covers the other one.

I trust you already know how to make the red translucent, either by using `opacity` or setting the colour using `rgba`.

I hope that helps.

Answer (score 1):

You have to use the pseudo elements `:after` & `:before` to achieve the bulge in the otherwise straight `div`.

You may try something like this:

```css
div {
  height: 30px;
  width: 200px;
  background-color: red;
  position: relative;
}

div:after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  width: 0px;
  height: 0;
  border-left: 10px solid transparent;
  border-right: 10px solid transparent;
  border-top: 10px solid #fff;
  margin: auto;
}

div:before {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: -8px;
  width: 0px;
  height: 0;
  border-left: 12px solid transparent;
  border-right: 12px solid transparent;
  border-top: 10px solid red;
  margin: auto;
}
```

```html
<div></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Since you didn't provide a fiddle so use below solution as a guide. CSS will produces curved edges that you join together to produce desired results.

```
div.arrow-curved { 
    width: 120px; 
    height: 80px; 
    background: red; 
    position: relative; 
    -moz-border-radius: 10px; 
    -webkit-border-radius: 10px; 
    border-radius: 10px; 
} 

div.arrow-curved:before { 
    content:""; 
    position: absolute; 
    right: 100%; 
    top: 26px; 
    width: 0; 
    height: 0; 
    border-top: 13px solid transparent; 
    border-right: 26px solid red; 
    border-bottom: 13px solid transparent; 
}
```

For more reference for CSS shapes: https://css-tricks.com/examples/ShapesOfCSS/